# @react-native-firebase/messaging not getting device token in real ios device

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I am using react-native-firebase v8 and react-native v0.61.2. I have recently upgraded my react-native version from 0.61 to 0.61.2. In android everything works perfect but in ios **real device** messaging.getToken() throw error in catch block, not getting any token.

Error:

[image]

my FCM-service file

```
class FcmService {

register = (onRegister,onNotification, onOpenNotification) =>{
    this.checkPermission(onRegister)
    // when register function call that time we create notification listener
    this.createNoitificationListeners(onRegister, onNotification, onOpenNotification)
}

registerAppWithFCM = async () => {
    if(Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();
        await messaging().setAutoInitEnabled(true);
    }
}

checkPermission = (onRegister) => {
    messaging().hasPermission()
        .then(enabled  => {
            if (enabled) {
                Alert.alert('enabled')
                //user has permission
                this.getToken(onRegister)
            } else {
                //user don't have permission
                this.requestPermission(onRegister)
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            let err = `check permission error${error}`
            Alert.alert(err)
        // console.log("[FCMService] Permission rejected", error)
    })
}

getToken = async (onRegister) => {
    let fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem(Constants.FCM_TOKEN);
    if(!fcmToken) {
        messaging().getToken()
        .then(fcmToken => {
            Alert.alert(fcmToken)
            if (fcmToken) {
                onRegister(fcmToken)
            } else {
                // console.log("[FCMService] User does not have a device token")
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            let err = `FCm token get error${error}`
            Alert.alert(err)
        // console.log("[FCMService] getToken rejected ", error)
    })
    }
    else {

    }
}

requestPermission = (onRegister) => {
    messaging().requestPermission().then(() => {
        this.getToken(onRegister)
    }).catch(error => {
        // console.log("[FCMService] Requested persmission rejected ", error)
    })
}

deletedToken = async () => {
    await messaging().deleteToken()
        .catch(error => {
            // console.log("Delected token error ", error)
        })
}

createNoitificationListeners = (onRegister, onNotification, onOpenNotification) => {

    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
        Alert.alert(remoteMessage)
        // console.log("[FCMService] onNotificationOpenedApp Notification caused app to open from background state:", remoteMessage);
        if(remoteMessage) {
            onOpenNotification(remoteMessage)
        }
    });

    // when the application is opened form a quit state
    messaging()
        .getInitialNotification()
        .then(remoteMessage => {
            Alert.alert(remoteMessage)
            // console.log('[FCMService] getInitialNotification Notification caused app to open from quit state:', remoteMessage);
            if (remoteMessage) {
                onOpenNotification(remoteMessage)
            }
        }
    );

    // Foreground state messages
    this.messageListener = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
        Alert.alert(remoteMessage)
         //console.log("[FCMService] A new FCM message arrived", remoteMessage);
        if(remoteMessage) {
            let notification = null;
            if(Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                notification = remoteMessage
            } else {
                notification = remoteMessage
            }
            onNotification(notification);
        }
    });

    // Triggered when have new token
    messaging().onTokenRefresh(fcmToken => {
        // console.log("New token refresh: ", fcmToken)
        onRegister(fcmToken)
    })

}

unRegister = () => {
    this.messageListener()
}
```

}

in `App.js` file i called that method

```
fcmService.registerAppWithFCM();
fcmService.register(this.onRegister, this.onNotification, this.onOpenNotification);
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use community/push notification ios dependency and ask for permission.
using that I was able to fix this

Comment: permission is working fine but register method is not working and hence firebase doesn't provide any FCM token. this is only happening in ios real device

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also enable remoteMessages in your firebase.json alternatively enable like this

```
await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();
const token = await messaging().getToken();
```